# How can I make a listview with more than a title?

Tags: android, listview

I would like to have a special listview with a title, couple of sub-categories, and a picture. The picture below is a rough idea of how I would like to lay it out. I am very new to android so keep in mind that details really helps me. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an xml layout that is used for each ListView item.  If you haven't yet, read through [Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) for an introduction to the different layout types.  There are also a "Hello layout" tutorial for each layout type, linked from that page.

In this case, you could use a horizontal LinearLayout with a vertical LinearLayout and an ImageView inside of it.

To bind your objects to the views within your ListView item, use a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html).  You can find a number of tutorials on SimpleAdapters if you search around, for [example](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/my-first-meeting-with-simpleadapter.html).

Comment: Thanks I have gone through the Hello View Tutorials but they are very vague. That tutorial you gave is great. I'm finding that it is hard to discover these tools unless you have a lot of experience. When you explained it like you did it makes perfect sense. Thanks again